# Regular expression to get page title

Tags: php, regex

There are lots of answers to this question, but not a single complete one:

With using one regular expression, how do you extract page title from `<title>Page title</title>`?

There are several other cases how title tags are typed, such as:

```
<TITLE>Page title</TITLE>

<title>
 Page title</title>
<title>
 Page title
</title>

<title lang="en-US">Page title</title>
```

...or any combination of above.

And it can be on its own line or in between other tags:

```
<head>
  <title>Page title</title>
</head>

<head><title>Page title</title></head>
```

Thanks for help in advance.

UDPATE: So, the regex approach might not be the best solution to this. Which PHP based HTML parser could handle all scenarios, where HTML is well formed (or not so well)?

UPDATE 2: sp00m's regex (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13510307/1844607) seems to be working in all cases. I'll get back to this if needed.

Comment: Thats one of the reasons, why regex is the wrong tool for this job. Why don't you use a html parser?

Comment: Any ideas which PHP based HTML parser to use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Use a HTML parser instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1225328). But in case of:

```
<title[^>]*>(.*?)</title>
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com?32t69)

Comment: Turned into PHP `preg_match("/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>/",$html,$title);` didn't get the title from http://www.gameinformer.com/b/features/archive/2012/11/21/the-top-10-grand-theft-auto-characters-of-all-time.aspx

Comment: @Jari Use the `i` (case insensitive), the `m` (multiline) and the `s` (the dot metachar includes new lines) flags, i.e. `/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>/ims`. See [pattern modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Comment: This seems to be working, thanks! I'll get back to this if I find some new scenarios where it fails.

Comment: @Jari Moreover, double-escape the nested `/` char: `/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/title>/ims`

Comment: Or use something different as delimiter. preg_match("#<title[^>]*>(.*?)</title>#Umsi", $html, $matches);

Comment: Also it is a good idea to cut html content's first x caharacters like mb_substr($urlContent, 0, 20000, "utf-8"); i prefer first 20000.

Answer (score 2):

Use the DOMDocument class:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$titles = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title");
echo $titles->item[0]->nodeValue;
```

Comment: This approach could work, but it seems to fail in cases where the HTML isn't as "validated" as it should be. Such as this: http://www.gameinformer.com/b/features/archive/2012/11/21/the-top-10-grand-theft-auto-characters-of-all-time.aspx

Comment: @Jari What does that link have to do with anything? Could you please provide some cases where a regex is a superior approach due to the html not being "validated" enough? The less well formed your HTML the more impossible it becomes to come up with one catchall regex.

Comment: That's just one example of many pages this should be able to get the page title from. If a HTML parser is better than any regex, it suits well for me, but then the real question is: which HTML parser handles unvalidated (broken) HTML good enough?

Comment: @Jari Could you please give me some sample HTML instead of pointing me to your website?

Comment: I'll just copy-paste what's on there: `</script><title>
 The Top 10 Grand Theft Auto Characters of All Time - Features - www.GameInformer.com
</title></head>` but it might not be exact match, since there might be some characters lost. (Edit: Yup, newlines and empty spaces are missing)

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
<title>[\s\S]*?</title>
```

Comment: Not sure if I got it entirely right in PHP `preg_match("/<head>[\s]*?<title>[\s\S]*?<\/title>[\s]*?<\/head>/",$html,$title);`, but this didn't get the page title from here: http://www.gameinformer.com/b/features/archive/2012/11/21/the-top-10-grand-theft-auto-characters-of-all-time.aspx